# I cant enter characters in password field. I can enter number only

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I used the following code to encrypt the password using md5 and store it in the database.

```
public partial class register : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Shihab-PC;Initial Catalog=test;User ID=sh;Password=admin1");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection myconnection;
            SqlCommand mycommand;
            string query;
            myconnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Shihab-PC;Initial Catalog=test;User ID=sh;Password=admin1");
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                myconnection.Open();
                query = "select * from Users";
                mycommand = new SqlCommand(query, myconnection);
                dr = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();
                int count = Convert.ToInt16(dr[0].ToString());
                while (dr.Read())
                { count++; }
                TextBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(count + 1);

            }



        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection myconnection;
            SqlCommand mycommand;
            int ra;
            string query;
            myconnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Shihab-PC;Initial Catalog=test;User ID=sh;Password=admin1");
            myconnection.Open();



            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            Byte[] hashedDataBytes;
            UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
            hashedDataBytes = md5hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(TextBox2.Text));

            StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(hashedDataBytes.Length * 2);
            foreach (Byte b in hashedDataBytes)
            {
                string x = b.ToString() + " ";
                hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);

            }


            query = "Insert into Users values(" + TextBox4.Text + ",'" +
                                                   TextBox3.Text + "','" +

                                                   hex.ToString() + "','" +

                                                   TextBox1.Text + "','" +
                                                    TextBox5.Text + "','" +
                                                    TextBox6.Text + "','" +
                                                    TextBox7.Text + "','" +
                                                    TextBox8.Text + "','" +
                                                    TextBox9.Text + "','" +
                                                   TextBox10.Text + "')";

            mycommand = new SqlCommand(query, myconnection);
            ra = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (ra > 0)
            {
                string msg = "alert('Record Inserted Sucessfuly')";
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Message", msg, true);
                Response.Redirect("signin.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                string msg = "alert('Unable to Insert Record ')";
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Message", msg, true);
            }
            myconnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

the problem when I run the code and enter characters in password field I get the following
 error (Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1234567yY' to data type int.)

Comment: Good lord... *please* read up on SQL Injection as soon as possible.

Comment: I didnt Understand what  do you mean . thank you for your help

Comment: Run a Google search for "SQL Injection" so you understand why executing a string that is built from user input is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

**First Option:**  Specify the columns in your [INSERT SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx).

```
INSERT INTO Users (UserID, Col2, Col3 ...) VALUES (...)
```

**Second Option:** See what `query` actually is and debug it with SQL Server Management Studio.

Put a breakpoint on this line and check the Locals for `query`.

```
mycommand = new SqlCommand(query, myconnection);
```

**Third Option:** Use a parameterized query and set the values in the Parameters property of the command.

Those maintaining this after you will thank you and you'll get rid of the SQL injection possibility in this section of code.

Comment: Can you explain with more detail? Im beginner in asp.net and thank you for your help.

Comment: second option and third option

Comment: For the third option:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx

Comment: For the second, are you not familiar with debugging an application at all?

Comment: for second option I dont  know how debug it with SQL Server Management Studio. I debug with visual studio

Comment: the debugging there is really just running it.

Comment: so how debug using SQL Server Management Studio and what is the difference  between debugging in visual studio and debugging in  SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: that's a whole new question...  just copy the query text into SSMS and run it.  It should err on you.  Then fix it there and translate the changes back to your VS project.

Comment: An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Add a name or single space as the alias name.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a **lot** of issues.

It's going to leak connections, it's ripe for SQL Injection, and it's very brittle.  Taking these one at a time.

First, you should wrap every object that implements IDisposable in a using clause.  This is the best practice way of making sure the objects get cleaned up at the appropriate time.  See this question for an example: [c# closing sqlconnection and sqldatareader or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385837/c-closing-sqlconnection-and-sqldatareader-or-not/4385896#4385896)

On a very lightly used system you may not notice the issue do to connection pool recycling.  However, as soon as you get any level of traffic this code will blow up in interesting and sometimes unpredictable ways.

Second, to help protect against sql injection do NOT use string concatenation to build your queries.  Instead use parameters.  @decyclone's answer shows an example of how to do this.  It would be trivial to crack the code you have now.

Third, your queries are very brittle.  Your insert statement depends on the order of the fields in the users table and, therefore, that the table is never modified.  The first time you either reorder those fields OR add a new one your code will break.  And you won't find this bug until runtime.  You should explicitly set which fields you are inserting into.  For example:

```
insert into Users(Username,Password) values('SomeUser', 'SomePassword')
```

Comment: I didnt understand all your answer.I dont know what is sql injuction . I followed @decyclone's answer and as I said I have another feild UserId that is auto generated . when I run code  and entered my data I got the following error (Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'UserId' to data type int).

Comment: @shihab: See this for info on SQL Injection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: what I understand now that I have change my code and follow  @decyclone's answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to insert a `varchar` value into an `int` type column in database.

A better way to go would be using [`Command Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) instead to prevent errors like this.

### Example:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Insert into Users(UserName, Password) Values(@UserName, @Password)", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", "SomeUser"); // You pass something else instead of "SomeUser"
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", "Password"); // You pass something else instead of "Password"
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I tried your code and I added also userid feild when i run it I got error (Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'UserId' to data type int).  the id is auto generated

Comment: @Shihab: if the userid is auto generated then it shouldn't be in your insert statement.  Take it back out and run decyclone's answer as is.

Comment: I followed your answer and I got this error(Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserId', table 'test.dbo.Users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.)

Comment: @shihab: It sounds like the User ID is not an identity column.  Can you script the table and provide it's definition?

Comment: It has 10 feilds (UserId,UserName,Password and other feilds. the UserId data type int and not primary key .

Comment: for User Id I made a change now I changed it to allow null. I run the code no error found but when I checked the the database I found the Id empty ,in User name field I found the text user name I but it should the name of the user that I typed and the same with the password